# Springboot multipart temmporary files are not deleted

Tags: java, spring

Springboot multipart temmporary files are not deleted. Which Springboot version should be upgraded? Currently I am using 2.7.2

Automatically delete the multipart temporary files under /tmp directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27633.
You might increase the value maxInMemorySize (DefaultPartHttpMessageReader). Spring 6.x has some auto clean up features.